# moment.js being added to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

I'm trying to rack my head on why the object contents of my variable is being added to my array instead of an actual Date object

```
async function timeShift(dayWeek = 'weeks', num = 4) {
    console.log('Timeshift Start');
    formattedDate = moment(Date.parse(start_date))
    let apptStartArr = [formattedDate]
    let lastApptonArr = apptStartArr[apptStartArr.length - 1]
    i = 1
    while (lastApptonArr.isBefore(Date.now())) {
        newStart = lastApptonArr.add(num, `${dayWeek}`).toDate().getTime()
        apptStartArr.push(newStart)
        console.log(`${i}, ${newStart}`);
        i += 1
    }
    //Must pop the last array off and return
    console.log(apptStartArr);
    console.log(lastApptonArr);

    return lastApptonArr
}
```

It yields the following

```
[ moment("2020-01-30T13:00:00.000"),
  1568318400000,
  1570737600000,
  1573160400000,
  1575579600000,
  1577998800000,
  1580418000000 ]
```

Sorry for the sloppy code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your first value is a moment object. you need to convert this to timestamp

```
let apptStartArr = [formattedDate]
```

SHould be

```
let apptStartArr = [formattedDate.toDate().getTime()]
```

And if you want Date objects instead of timestamp number, don't call `getTime()`

```
let apptStartArr = [formattedDate.toDate()];
```

And

```
newStart = lastApptonArr.add(num, `${dayWeek}`).toDate();
```